# Is it possible to use wildcards on column variable?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using a datatable to store strings to compare to input in one of my programs. However input is sometimes given with a variable attached to the end.

Ex. 'My Search String MM/dd/yyyy'

In the table I only store 'My Search String' WITHOUT the 'MM/dd/yyyy' attached. Is there a way to use wildcards to do something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE SEARCH_STRING% LIKE 'My Search String MM/dd/yyyy'
```

I don't want to just trim off the variable part of the string in my program as there are other search strings with other variable formats and I want to avoid hard coding it.

Comment: Is search_string supposed to represent the name of a column or a value of record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
WHERE 'My Search String MM/dd/yyyy' LIKE CONCAT(SEARCH_STRING, '%')
```

I think this does what you describe.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I was trying to add the wildcard like SEARCH_STRING + %.